# Different size brackets for binomial coefficient in inline mode using MathJax

Tags: mathjax

While using MathJax to typeset binomial coefficients, I came across this problem of different sized brackets if my lower index contains the '0' character. Is there anyway to make the brackets the same size?

[image: Binomial Coefficients Brackets]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While MathJax uses a syntax very similar to TeX/LaTeX, it doesn't use TeX for rendering, so there's nothing that can be done on the TeX side.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. If I may ask, is there an appropriate StackExchange for questions directly related to MathJax?

Comment: You can use the mathjax tag on stackoverflow, or more directly use the mathjax help forum

Comment: This issue is fixed in v2.5 (currently in beta, with the official release very soon now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a LaTeX-based solution. The macro `\mychoose` should be used only in "text-style" math mode. (I trust it's not too difficult to adapt it to MathJax.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\newcommand{\mychoose}[2]{\bigl({{#1}\atop#2}\bigr)}
\begin{document}
$\sum_{k=0}^n \mychoose{n}{k}=\mychoose{n}{0}+\cdots+\mychoose{n}{n}.$
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: If you want square brackets instead of round parentheses, simply adjust the code in the `\mychoose` macro.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this is easily adapted in MathJax using macros.